# Regex Anything But Letters

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm working on a Nano color code for Assembly.

I had simply this (only including eax and ebx as there are dozens of them):

```
color brightcyan "(eax|ebx)"
```

However, they may be highlighted in other words such as "Hesitate" where "esi" is colored cyan.

Then I used this:

```
color brightcyan "(\ |\[|\+|\-|\]\*")(eax|ebx)"
```

Which works, but turns other sybols cyan when I have them in another color (such as `[`). However, I want it to turn blue ONLY if it's NOT surrounded by alphanumeric characters. Any other symbols should not hinder the coloring, nor should they be colored.

Answer (score 3):

Try `"\b(eax|ebx)\b"`. This will only match if it's not surrounded by alphanumeric characters or `_`.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
color brightcyan "\b(eax|ebx)\b"
```

Answer (score 3):

You have some options.

The simpelest is to use the word boundary marker `\b`.

```
\b(eax|ebx)\b
```

Will match eax or ebx only when it forms a whole word.
Note that this does not quite match what you ask for, since it looks for a distinction between word and non-word characters, rather than alphanumeric contra non alphanumeric.  So my suggestion would not match in the case of "_eax"